# how to redirect to root folder after logout?

Tags: php

i am in this address in my project

```
localhost/v1.2/login_pane/login_pane-personnelselect/profile/profile.php
```

and i want to redirect to this page `[localhost/v1.2/login_pane/loginmain.html`
and the page always redirect me to `localhost/v1.2/login_pane/login_pane-personnelselect/login_pane/index.html`

i have this php code in my `logout.php` but it doestnt work

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(session_destroy())
    {
    header("Location: ../../loginmain.html");
    }
    ?>
```

how will i able to make it?

Comment: Try `../../` in your URL. A single `./` means current directory whereas `../` means one lower, `.../` won't mean two directories lower

Comment: http://localhost/v1.2/login_pane/login_pane-personnelselect/login_pane/index.html

i was redirected to this link

Comment: Is your loginmain.html redirecting. If not then you are either showing the wrong code or the file address is incorrect, please confirm both

Comment: i am redirected but i was redirected to wrong address

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: ../../loginmain.html");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
header("Location: ../../loginmain.html");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have try with following code:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["nome"]);  // where $_SESSION["nome"] is your own variable. if you do not     have one use only this as follow **session_unset();**
header("Location: ../../loginmain.html");
```